# Xmpp ejabberd and add-user command

Tags: xmpp, ejabberd

I have two ejabberd servers, one local one distant online on foobar.com.

Using xmpp pidgin console i can send iq stanzas for tests:

**Local server** hostname is eepc

```
<iq to='eeepc' from='greg@eeepc' id='get-registred-users-num-1' type='set'>
    <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' action='execute' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-registered-users-num'/>

</iq>

<iq from='eeepc' to='greg@eeepc/3493331071251540036345753' id='get-registred-users-num-1' type='result'>
    <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' sessionid='2009-08-29T14:01:55.714639Z' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-registered-users-num' status='completed'>
        <x xmlns='jabber:x:data'>
            <field type='hidden' var='FORM_TYPE'>
                <value>http://jabber.org/protocol/admin</value>
            </field>
            <field type='text-single' label='Number of registered users' var='registeredusersnum'>
                <value>7</value>
            </field>
        </x>
    </command>
</iq>
```

**Distant Server**

```
<iq to='foobar.com' from='greg@foobar.com' id='get-registred-users-num-1' type='set'>
    <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' action='execute' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-registered-users-num'/>
</iq>

<iq from='foobar.com' to='greg@foobar.com/36523779951251567671615394' id='get-registred-users-num-1' type='error'>
    <command xmlns='http://jabber.org/protocol/commands' action='execute' node='http://jabber.org/protocol/admin#get-registered-users-num'/>
    <error code='404' type='cancel'>
        <item-not-found xmlns='urn:ietf:params:xml:ns:xmpp-stanzas'/>
    </error>
</iq>
```

I don't understand why i get a , i could not see any particular options to tell the server to accept commands from remote ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Maybe `mod_configure` is simply not loaded on the distant server.
You can check via `lists:member(mod_configure, gen_mod:loaded_modules("foobar.com")).` in an ejabberd admin shell.
I cannot imagine that this is about being a remote user, because no s2s connection is needed between foobar.com and greg@foobar.com.

Answer (score 0):

Looking in  [the mod_configure.erl source code](https://forge.process-one.net/browse/ejabberd/trunk/src/mod_configure.erl?r=HEAD) there seems to be an ACL check to make sure the configure adhoc commands are only allowed when the requester is on a user account has configure priv on that virtual host. By default I think they don't.

```
acl:match_rule(LServer, configure, From)
```

You may need to add something like...

```
{access, configure, [{allow, greg@foobar.com}]}.
```

...to your ejabberd.cfg file.